# Requirejs order not respected

Tags: javascript, requirejs

i have a structure of a lot of files, for example a take only 3.

File1 :

```
require(["plugin1","plugin2","jquery","jquery-ui"],function(){
   console.log('File1');
});
```

plugin1 :

```
require(["plugin1dependency"],function(){
   console.log('Plugin1');
   //Some code that require plugin1dependency
});
```

plugin1dependency:

```
require(["jquery"],function(){
   console.log('Plugin1dependency');
});
```

In the console i found a error in plugin1 cause the code of plugin1dependency is executed after the code of plugin1.

The console.logs are executed in this way :

Plugin1 - Plugin1dependency - File1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're only using require, and not define. Instead of saying

```
require(["plugin1dependency"],function(){
   console.log('Plugin1');
   //Some code that require plugin1dependency
});
```

you'd want to define plugin1 as a module, using a shim, or by modifying the file

```
define(["plugin1dependency"], function() {
   console.log('Plugin1');
   //Some code that require plugin1dependency
});
```

Comment: i've tried before with the define, even with define(["plugin1dependency"], and define("plugin1",["plugin1dependency"].
and the result is the same of require